# Common Table Expression return Nothing but "command executed"

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, postgresqlstudio

i have a user table, a pro table and a pro_users table to join : user -- many to many --> pro

i want to get the number of users, the number of pro joined to user AND the sum of user+member (this seams not relevant but it's just for testing)

i have this query :

```
WITH sums AS(
  SELECT COUNT(user.user_id) as usercount, COUNT(pro.pro_id) as procount
  FROM user
  LEFT JOIN pro_users ON user.user_id = pro_users.user_id
  LEFT JOIN pro ON pro_users.pro_id = pro.pro_id
)
SELECT usercount, procount, usercount+procount as total FROM sums
```

the inner select work as expected when queried alone. I've tried to only get members from the outter select and absolutely no result show up and i get

> message:Command Executed

in PostgreSql Studio.

desired output:

```
| usercount | procount | total |  
--------------------------------  
|   1000    |    500   |  1500 |
```

What am i mising?

Thanks

Comment: what returns executed outside cte block?

Comment: Post sample data and desired output

Comment: nothing but : `message:Command Executed`

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto i've updated my question

Comment: Does it work with `psql` or another SQL client?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it works like a charm in psql ... Thanks! hope this will work in my app to

Comment: Sounds like a bug in PostgreSQL Studio then. You could rewrite your statement to `select usercount, procount, usercount+procount as total FROM ( .... ) as sums` to avoid the CTE